# Json Schema pattern for integer values

Tags: jsonschema

Is there a way to verify the pattern of an integer value?

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "definitions": {},
    "id": "http://example.com/example.json",
    "properties": {
        "test": {
            "type": "integer",
            "pattern":"1343"
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
}
```

Just a little test JSON

```
{
  "test": 1
}
```

This always validates true with http://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/

I know that I can make a small workaround by using "minimum":1, "maximum":1 but this looks kind of strange and needs 2 lines for 1 validation.

Is there a way to check like on strings with "pattern" or anything else? Regex ^1$ doesn't work either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pattern` keyword only applies to strings.  The best way to constrain a number to a specific value is to use `enum` or the new `const` keyword.

```
{
  "enum": [1343]
}
```

-

```
{
  "const": 1343
}
```

Comment: enum validates right, const somehow doesn't ("const":2 validates my "test":1 right)

Comment: `const` is seriously brand new (a couple weeks).  I only know of one validator (AJV) that supports it.  Yours probably doesn't yet.